# Eliminar previsualización de imagen en Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, imagen, laravel-livewire

Quisiera saber si alguien sabe como puedo eliminar la previsualización temporaria de imágenes en Laravel Livewire.

Tengo el siguiente input file:

```
 @if ($imagenes)
  <small>previsualización:</small>

    @foreach($imagenes as $img)

        <img class="img-fluid w-25 my-2 contenedor-img" src="{{ $img->temporaryUrl() }}">

     @endforeach

 @endif
```

Requiero agregar un botón para eliminar alguna de las imágenes seleccionadas.

La carga la realizo de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

         $img = imgPropiedades::create([
           'url' => $imgUrl,
           'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
         ]);
    }
```

Pero la eliminación de alguna imagen me está complicando.

Comment: Sólo debes utilizar el método delete para eliminar dichas imágenes `$img->delete()`

Comment: De todas maneras, esa imagen subida temporalmente sólo dura 30 minutos